# Regarding visa to Finland

Tags: indian-citizens, schengen-visas, applications, switzerland, finland

I am living in India. I have a conference in Finland from 26 June to 1 July 2022 and also a workshop in Switzerland from 4 July to 8 July 2022. Although my first entry is Finland but can I take Switzerland visa and enter to Finland then go to Switzerland? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

In principle you need to apply for your visa from the country which is most important to your trip.
So if Switzerland is the more important conference you can apply for a visa from that country.

In your case Finland seems more likely, as the time spend will be about equal and you are going to Finland first.